# Can I use Ajax to switch divs?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a voting system for a model Subrating where, if a user votes by clicking on an icon, then his ip address is added to a list, which prevents him from voting again, and the blank voting icon is replaced by a green voting icon, both of which are defined in seperate divs. I would like to ajaxify this process. I have figured out how to update the vote count with Ajax, but is there a way to switch the vote icon divs when the button is clicked?

Here's what I have so far: Say I want to switch `<div id="<%= subrating.name %>upz">` to `<div id="voted">`.

**views/things/show.html.erb:**

```
    <% if ((!@subratingip.include? request.remote_ip) && (!@subratingunip.include? request.remote_ip)) %>
      <div id="subratings" >
        <div id="<%= subrating.name %>"><%= number_to_percentage(subrating.rating, precision: 0) %></div>
        <div id="<%= subrating.name %>upz">
          <a id="<%= subrating.name.downcase %>_link"><%= link_to image_tag("UpArrowGray.png", alt: "votedown", class: 'uparrowsub' ), upvote_subrating_path(:id => subrating.id), method: :get %></a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $("#<%= subrating.name.downcase %>_link").click(function () {
            $.get( "<%= upvote_subrating_path(:id => subrating.id) %>", function( data ) {
              $('#<%= subrating.name %>').html(data + ' %');
            });
          });
        </script>
```

---

**controllers/subratings_controller.rb**

```
  def upvote
    @subrating = Subrating.find(params[:id])
    UpVote.create!(ip: request.remote_ip, vanishing: false, voteable_id: params[:id], voteable_type: 'Subrating')
    redirect_to @subrating.thing
    render text: ((@subrating.up_votes.count.to_f + 2).to_f / (@subrating.up_votes.count.to_f + @subrating.down_votes.count.to_f + 3 ).round(1).to_f * 100).to_s
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it turns out I can just insert an image as html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#<%= subrating.name.downcase %>_link").click(function () {
        $.get( "<%= upvote_subrating_path(:id => subrating.id) %>", function( data ) {
          $('#<%= subrating.name %>').html(data + ' %');
          $('#<%= subrating.name %>'upz).html( '<%= image_tag("UpArrowGreen.png" %>');
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line `$("#<%= subrating.name %>upz).attr("id", "voted");` to your click which would change the id of the div. However, it seems that you are setting the image based on the contents inside the div, which means you should remove/hide the div#upz and add/show the div#voted.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#<%= subrating.name.downcase %>_link").click(function () {
        $.get( "<%= upvote_subrating_path(:id => subrating.id) %>", function( data ) {
          $('#<%= subrating.name %>').html(data + ' %');
        });
        $("#<%= subrating.name %>upz").attr("id", "voted");
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, changing the div id works, but you're correct, I want to change the content. How can I remove/hide/add/show divs?

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to use class based selectors and CSS.

```
<div id="subratings">
    <div class="subrating">
        <ul class="actions">
            <li class="upvote"><%= link_to("Upvote", upvote_subrating_path(subrating)) %></li>
            <li class="downvote disabled"><%= link_to("Downvote", downvote_subrating_path(subrating)) %></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also generally strongly advise against mixing ERB & javascript. Put your javascript into separate asset files. Otherwise you often end up with a sludge of HTML, javascript and ruby with ajax calls running around in circles.

```
// This delegates an event handler to any link in div.actions 
$('.subrating .actions').on('click', 'a', function(event){
    var $link = $(this);
    var $actions = $link.parents('.actions');

    if (!$link.attr('disabled')) {
        var promise = $.get( $obj.attr('href') );
        promise.done(function(){
            $actions.children('.upvote, .downvote').toggleClass('disabled');
            $actions.find('a').not($link).removeAttr( 'disabled' );
            $link.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    }

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Also you got way to much logic in your view. Your view should NOT be responsible for who gets to vote on what.

Comment: You mean preventing one ip address from voting twice? How else would you recommend I regulate that?

Comment: In a helper method or in your controller. Your views should have conditionals like  `if can_vote? do` or `if logged_in?` tops.

Comment: Is my current model slowing down the load time?

Comment: Not necessarily - but complex views are hard to test and tricky to debug and generally regarded as poor MVC practice. http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/refactoring-logic-from-a-rails-view/